# Image loaded twice in background-image in css file with angular universal build

Tags: angular, universal

I set image to background-image for div in home page in my site in scss file:

```
    background-image: url('../../../assets/images/map.png');
```

this work correctly when using `ng serve`.

But when I build with `npm run build:ssr` and run `node server.js`, the image is loaded twice - first loading fails, and second succeeds:

[image]
[amyar24.com](https://amyar24.com)

in `server.js` changed to `background-image: url('map.png');`

How to avoid loading that image twice?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In CSS you dont have to write  `background-image` instead you can write CSS as follows

```
.mycssclass{
    background: url('/assets/myimage.png');
    background-size: contain;
}
```

P.S. - it works for me and it dont loads the image twice